# mysql error while trying INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql

Any idea why this error keeps coming up on this piece of code?

```
"INSERT INTO upcomuser_lv (id, user, month, date_start, date_end, sick, holiday, comp, military)
VALUES         ('id', '$user', 'November', '2015-11-1', '2015-11-30', '8', '24', '0', '0' ),
               ('id','$user','December', '2015-12-1', '2015-12-31', '8', '16', '16', '0'),
               ('id','$user','Janruary', '2016-1-1', '2016-1-31', '8', '16', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','February', '2016-2-1', '2016-2-29', '8', '8', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','March', '2015-3-1', '2015-3-31', '8', '0', '0', '0' ),
               ('id','$user','April', '2015-4-1', '2015-4-30', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','May', '2016-5-1', '2016-5-31', '8', '8', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','June', '2016-6-1', '2016-6-30', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','July', '2015-7-1', '2015-7-31', '8', '8', '0', '0' ),
               ('id','$user','August', '2015-8-1', '2015-8-31', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','September', '2016-9-1', '2016-9-30', '8', '0', '0', '120'),
               ('id','$user','October', '2016-10-1', '2016-10-31', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=VALUES('user'), month=VALUES('month'), date_start=VALUES('date_start'), date_end=VALUES('date_end'), sick=VALUES('sick'), holiday=VALUES('holiday'), comp=VALUES('comp'), military=VALUES('military')";
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=VALUES('user'),
>   month=VALUES('month'), date_start=V' at line 14

Comment: Trailing comma at the end of the final set of values?

Comment: I deleted my answer because people didn't seem to like it but you have issues outside of the syntax error as well. You are inserting the same values over and over and will update the dupes incorrectly in your UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing comma before `ON`

```
"INSERT INTO upcomuser_lv (id, user, month, date_start, date_end, sick, holiday, comp, military)
VALUES         ('id', '$user', 'November', '2015-11-1', '2015-11-30', '8', '24', '0', '0' ),
               ('id','$user','December', '2015-12-1', '2015-12-31', '8', '16', '16', '0'),
               ('id','$user','Janruary', '2016-1-1', '2016-1-31', '8', '16', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','February', '2016-2-1', '2016-2-29', '8', '8', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','March', '2015-3-1', '2015-3-31', '8', '0', '0', '0' ),
               ('id','$user','April', '2015-4-1', '2015-4-30', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','May', '2016-5-1', '2016-5-31', '8', '8', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','June', '2016-6-1', '2016-6-30', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','July', '2015-7-1', '2015-7-31', '8', '8', '0', '0' ),
               ('id','$user','August', '2015-8-1', '2015-8-31', '8', '0', '0', '0'),
               ('id','$user','September', '2016-9-1', '2016-9-30', '8', '0', '0', '120'),
               ('id','$user','October', '2016-10-1', '2016-10-31', '8', '0', '0', '0')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=VALUES('user'), month=VALUES('month'), date_start=VALUES('date_start'), date_end=VALUES('date_end'), sick=VALUES('sick'), holiday=VALUES('holiday'), comp=VALUES('comp'), military=VALUES('military')";
```

Comment: trailing comma didnt fix it.

Comment: The `user=VALUES('user')` is using wrong quotes, use ` instead.

Comment: fixed it. the comma and quotes were wrong. thanks